# Passing type name as argument to a member template function

Tags: c++, templates

I have two similar structures which are slightly different in the packing. They are used in a member function of the another class. So can I write some template methods, with these structure as template parameter, to avoid duplication. So how to pass struct name itself for template initialization?

```
  struct header
    {
        char symbol[6];
    };

    struct headerV8
    {
       int id;
       char symbol[8];
    };

    class connection
     {
        connectionMgr _mgr;

        public:

        // here I want to pass T as only type; Class itself is not a template class 
        // but its method is template function.

        template<class T>
            void request(T); 
     };


     //template parameter is used to decide which struct to use header or headerV8.
     <template T>
     void connection::request(T)  
      {
         T a;
         strcpy(a.symbol, "AAPL");
         cout << a.symbol;
         mgr.socketSend(a);
      }

  calls to request
     if(versionV8)
         conn.request(headerV8);
     else
         conn.request(heaver);
```

Comment: Why not, but what is your question?

Comment: @Kuroi how to pass struct name itself for template initialization